# Magento 1.8 Customer login Confirmation key not receiving by the customer

Tags: magento-1.8, email, customer-account

While Creating a new account as new customer, I gave in the

> System->Configuration->Customer->Customer Configuration

Send

> Confirmation Key= Yes

But Account is getting created but the Confirmation key is not been sent to the mail which was given at the time of registration guyz please me

Answer (score 0):

see this answer may be this help you....And Describe your Question With Code if you created ...
And also Define In Detail what you want...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268829/magento-session-cookie-form-keys-not-working-correctly-magento-1-8-1